# Using a settings file with a different name is not working

Tags: azure-functions

- Function App name: microServiceBus.functions
- Tools used: VS2022 - Version 17.4.4 & Version 17.7.4
- .Net runtime: 6
- Runtime: dotnet-isolated
- Language: C#
- Core Tools Version:       4.0.5390 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
- Function Runtime Version: 4.25.3.21264

We have an function app used by many customers, hence we've had to updated the `local.settings.json` dependin on which the customer we've been working with. Upon migrating from v4 In-proc to v4 isolated we've instead created multiple settings files, one for each customer as this has worked fine for our web applications. However, using a settings file with a different name is not working.

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
        //config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true);
        config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.CUSTOMER.json", optional: true);
        
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
ConfigureLogging(logging => ...)
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureServices((context, services) => ...)
.Build();

host.Run();
```

Behavior:
If the `local.settings.json` does not exist, the process will not start with the following error:

```bash
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5390 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.25.3.21264

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
[2023-10-06T10:30:41.620Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.IncidentHandler_SendEmail'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
```

Interestingly, it seams the configuration is evaluated before the `ConfigureAppConfiguration` method is executed, as if I set a breakpoint in the method I can se the output of funciton list before the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: It is giving a warning for `"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"` value, instead you can keep the local.settings.json as is and create a separate json files for each customer. Refer https://www.tomfaltesek.com/azure-functions-local-settings-json-and-source-control/

Comment: I am getting the [output](https://i.imgur.com/cMhPdTy.png) along with warning message

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, you can't rename `local.settings.json` instead you can add a customized Json file and load the values with the help of [Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources) class or `program.cs` file.

As per [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local#local-project-files), `local.settings.json` is the default settings file used by Core Tools during local development only. Once you deployed the function to Azure, `local.settings.json` will no longer be required and the configuration related data will be fetched from azure app settings.

[image]

If you  will run **`func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated`** command, below default files will get created.

[image]

You can use the below startup class code to add a customized Json file for local development.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(namespaceName.StartUp))]

namespace namespaceName
{
    public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "local.settings.CUSTOMER.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to add a separate config file `local.settings.CUSTOMER.json` then you can make the following changes to achieve it.

I have added `local.settings.CUSTOMER.json`.

```json
{
  "Name": "Afreen"
}
```

Change the properties settings of the config file like below-

**Go to Properties**-

[image]

Change **`Copy to Output Directory to Copy always or Copy if newer`**.

[image]

Then the value will get updated in .csproj file as below-

```cs
<None Update="local.settings.CUSTOMER.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

**Program.cs**-

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
        config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true);
        config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.CUSTOMER.json", optional: true);

        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Function.cs**-

```cs
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }

    [Function(nameof(Function1))]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
        _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
        _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
        var settingValue = _config["Name"];
        _logger.LogInformation($"{settingValue}");
    }
}
```

**Output**-

[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to change the name of local.settings.json, I'm trying to add another settingsfile called local.settings.CUSTOMER.json, but it's not picking it up

Comment: The issue with this approach is that any custom settings.json file is not loaded into environment variables. local.settings.json values are automatically set as env vars, but if you rename that file (and also load it during startup) then they aren't set as env vars.